# Gnuplot - Variable xrange to plot only last week's worth of captured data

Tags: gnuplot

I am capturing data from a sensor and it is being outputted into a .dat file. I want to export this information into a plot using gnuplot and have it be completely autonomous to only display the last 7 days worth of collected data (no hard coding the dates, should adjust based on system time using the `time()` function)

If I hard code the date range, i.e. `set xrange ["07-25-16":"08-25-16"]`, I receive no errors and the code/plot runs smoothly. However, if I try to plot a function of time for the past seven days using the `time()` function, I receive the following error:

```
line 0: illegal month
```

Here is my collected data from the sensor (output.dat):

```
07-21-2015 15:21 0 0 0
07-23-2016 15:21 0 0 0
07-29-2016 15:21 0 1 -1
07-29-2016 15:21 1 1 0
07-29-2016 15:21 2 1 1
07-29-2016 15:21 3 1 2
07-29-2016 15:21 3 2 1
07-29-2016 15:21 4 2 2
07-29-2016 15:21 5 2 3
07-29-2016 15:21 5 3 2
07-29-2016 15:21 5 4 1
07-29-2016 15:21 5 5 0
07-29-2016 15:22 6 5 1
07-29-2016 15:22 6 6 0
07-29-2016 15:23 1 0 1
07-29-2016 15:23 1 1 0
```

Here is the code I am running (commented out the xrange that works, replaced with the one I am trying to implement):

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"
xstart=strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", time(0) - 604800)
xend=strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", time(0))
#set xrange ["07-25-16":"08-25-16"]
set xrange ["xstart" : "xend"]
set format x "%m-%d\n%H:%M"
set title "Sensor Data"
set xlabel "Date\nTime"
set ylabel "Number of Sensor Trips"
plot    "output.dat" using 1:4 skip 1 t "Exits" with linespoints, \
        "output.dat" using 1:3 skip 1 t "Entrances" with linespoints
set term png
set output "output.png"
replot
set term x11
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit 1 -- Gnuplot now not plotting correctly after string fix (removed `""` from the xrange to only show: `set xrange [xstart:xend]`:

[image: wrong image]

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: the stftime format include hours and minutes. Did you remove that?

Comment: I did not remove that, as I want to output hours and minutes on the graph as well. Is this the wrong way to think about it?

Comment: "xstart"  and "xend" are not date strings.  Remove the quotes around those?

Comment: the difference is, that your hardcoded string is only the month(working) and ur generated is not. so maybe sort this out first.
xstart and xend using as variables is true as well

Comment: The xstart and xend, without the date strings "", get rid of the error about illegal month BUT the graph is now not working. I will attach above so you can see

Comment: can u try to compare a hardcoded version with the generated?
output the strings and see wheres the difference

Comment: Simply use `set xrange[time(0) - 7*24*60*60:*]`, no need to Fiddle around with strings

Comment: The graph now looks like such [https://s32.postimg.org/iz18ls9t1/output.png] (I cannot add image to main post due to lower than 10 reputation)

When compared to the hardcoded version when generated, the dates are literally the exact same. Which is why this is throwing me through a loop. Now that the illegal month error is gone, I can no longer get a sensible plot

Comment: Christoph - that is a much more elegant solution, thank you. I still have the error with the plot (see image above) where it seems like no data is now being output onto the graph. Instead it is a straight and solid "1"

Comment: I don't have any problems with the data you give, see my answer for an image of my output. Maybe you had some old settings for the yrange in your interactive session?

Comment: Thank you all for your help on getting this solved, I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If plotting time data, you can specify the axis range using time string formatted the same way like in the data file, but you must not. You can simply use integers for this:

```
reset
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"
set xrange [time(0) - 7*24*60*60:]
set format x "%m-%d\n%H:%M"
set style data linespoints

plot "output.dat" using 1:4 skip 1 t "Exits", \
     "" using 1:3 skip 1 t "Entrances"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Christoph, that did it. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if you want to do what you had in your script, that is a range between two given dates, use `strptime` :

```
set xrange [strptime("%m-%d-%Y","07-25-16"):strptime("%m-%d-%Y","08-25-16")]
```